# Join tables, return all data from one and WHERE data from the other (if there is no data, return null)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, but I have difficulties writing the query.
I have tried LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT swimmer.id, pool,last_name, first_name, paid, membership.month, datePaid, membership.fee, membership.datePaid
FROM swimmer
LEFT JOIN membership 
ON  membership.swimmer_id = swimmer.id
WHERE membership.month = 'September' 
OR membership.month IS NULL;
```

When I use this code, I'm missing those who paid for August:

```
Pool     FirstName    LastName   DatePaid    Fee    Method
B        Sarah        Delt       null        null   null
B        Pavle        North      null        null   null
S        Daniel       Key        2018-09-01  2000   Cash
```

On my main page, I have dropdown with Months. I want to display all swimmers paid for that month as well those who didn't pay, but their values should be null (exept Pool, FirstName and SecondName)

Swimmer table:

```
NameID  PoolName  FirstName  LastName
1       B         Anna       Pier
2       B         Wolf       Sedveh
3       B         Sarah      Delt
4       B         Pavle      North
5       S         Daniel     Keys
```

Membership table:

```
ID  Year  Month     DatePaid    Fee   Method  SwimmerId(FK)
1   2017  August    2017-08-01  1000  Cash    1
2   2017  August    2017-08-01  2000  Cash    2
3   2017  September 2017-09-01  2000  Cash    5
```

At the end, I need table like this:

```
Pool     FirstName    LastName   DatePaid    Fee    Method
B        Anna         Pier       null        null   null
B        Wolf         Sedveh     null        null   null
B        Sarah        Delt       null        null   null
B        Pavle        North      null        null   null
S        Daniel       Keys       2017-09-01  2000   Cash
```

So, basically, I need a query which will show paid memberships for selected month (and year). For those who paid - return data, for those who didn't - return null. 
I hope that I explained well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT swimmer.id, pool,last_name, 
       first_name, paid, membership.month, 
       datePaid, membership.fee, membership.datePaid
FROM swimmer
LEFT JOIN membership 
  ON  membership.swimmer_id = swimmer.id
 AND  membership.month = 'September' 
 AND  membership.year = '2017'
```

For `LEFT JOIN`:

- if you want filter the `LEFT` table you add `WHERE` condition.
- for the `RIGHT` table you add `ON` condition.